# What is the default behavior of robots if there is no robots meta tag?

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt, meta-robots

Assuming I have a page without a *robots.txt* and without the *robots meta tag*. What is the default behavior of robots? Would they index the page and follow the links as in:

```
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
```

I'm asking because I want to know if I can safely remove the meta tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behaviour of robots if there is no *robots.txt* and robots meta tag is to follow links on the page and index it.

That's why `<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />` is not necessary if you want the default behaviour of robots for your page.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag has more on this and how combined directives are handled. Essentially, specifying it as "index, follow" has no effect at all.